# Преобразовать кол-во секунд с 1 января 1970 года в time_t

Tags: c++, c, время

Наивное преобразование вида:

```
int utc;
...
time_t t = (time_t)utc;
```

работает (в моем, конкретном случае), но (вроде как) не переносимо, т.к. time_t не обязан быть кол-вом секунд с 1 января 1970 года (для принимающих его функций, типа gmtime, localtime и т.п.).

Как реализовать переносимое преобразование в соответствии с высокими стандартами?

Comment: `time_t` - это, вообще-то, просто тип. Все равно что говорить, что `double` не обязан быть числом "пи"... Сформулируйте вопрос как-то более понятно, если можно...

Comment: @Harry Поправил, для буквоедов =)

Comment: Теперь стало еще запутаннее. `gmtime` принимает количество секунд от "эпохи" [(*Converts given time since epoch (a time_t value pointed to by time) into calendar time*)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime) - т.е. вы как раз обязаны передавать это время... Вернее, передавайте что хотите - но рассматривать переданное значение функция будет как время от начала эпохи. Как вы получаете ваше значение `utc`?

Comment: @Harry это да, но стандарт не уточняет в каких единицах, например это могут быть доли секунды.

Comment: А, теперь наконец-то понятно, в чем суть вопроса. Надо в стандарте покопаться...

Comment: А вроде time_t именно под количество секунд с 00:00 UTC 1.01.1970 до определённого момента и заточен. POSIX это утверждает, другие стандарты не опровергают... Или я совсем не понял вопроса...

Comment: Ну, вобщем, если компилятор POSIX-соответствующий, то это таки секунды. Так что либо получайте значение переносимым способом, типа через `time`, либо... Либо возьмите два значения `tm`, отличаюшиеся на точно известное время (ну, там, секунду) и сравните разность двух `mktime` - вот и получите цену деления в представлении времени...

Comment: Я бы и рад, но уважаемые источники пишут: Portable programs should not use values of this type directly, but always rely on calls to elements of the standard library to translate them to portable types. А само значение приходит извне (json от железки) в виде unix timestamp.

Comment: И часто вы хотите с компилятора на компилятор свою программу перетаскивать? :) Если уж очень не верится в POSIX, посчитайте разность, как я предложил, двух `mktime`.

Comment: Насколько я могу толковать источник, он призывает вас первым делом передать unixtime ctime()'у, а уже потом оперировать полученной структурой.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Вопрос в том, в каких единицах ожидают библиотечные функции значение времени. Т.е. если компилятор не заявлен как POSIX, он может например значение time_t интерпретировать в миллисекундах.

Comment: @Harry Можно и разницу посчитать, но нет же гарантии, что время представлено числом, которое равномерно увеличивается.

Comment: Да, только вряд ли какой-то компилятор рискнёт настолько ломать совместимость. Ну давайте взглянем на вещи реально: unixtime — это целые секунды. Нельзя просто так взять и поменять аргументы и возвращаемые значения стандартных функций.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Опираться на традиции вместо стандарта - большие дяди будут ругать =)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t - тот же самый источник? Слова "although not defined" — достаточная причина считать, что стандарт ничего не говорит по этому поводу, и можно опираться на традицию, не нарушая стандарта? :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82013/discussion-between-alexander-prokoshev-and-vladimir-gamalyan).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan *Можно и разницу посчитать, но нет же гарантии, что время представлено числом, которое равномерно увеличивается* - знаете, любая паранойя хороша в меру...

Comment: Задача стоит именно так? Т.е. нужно именно `int` в котором 32-битный unix time, перевести именно в `time_t`? Или всё-таки задача другая, а Вы именно так решили её решать?

Comment: @ixSci Все верно, есть int из внешнего источника, про который известно, что это число секунд от 1 Jan 1970, нужно скормить в gmtime, который принимает implementation-defined time_t.

Comment: По крайней мере эта [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime) утверждает -- *"The ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() functions all take an argument of data type time_t which represents calendar time. When interpreted as an absolute time value, it represents the number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)."*

Answer (score 5):

Если закрыть глаза на тег [c](/questions/tagged/c), то я бы предложил такое решение:

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    int utc = 123456;
    system_clock::time_point tp{seconds{utc}};
    auto tm = system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
}
```

Формально, до C++20 эпоха `system_clock` не должна совпадать с 1 января 1970 года, но по факту это так и есть. А в 20 году это закрепят в стандарте (если верить [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock)).